# Whats wrong in this code of Codeigniter view page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to iterate foreach loop to get list of Property details but this code shows nothing please anybody tell me what is wrong in my code
I am new to php.

```
<?php foreach ($this->Property_Model->getProperty() as $property): ?> 
    <div class='properties'>
        <div class='image-holder'><img src='images/properties/1.jpg' class='img-responsive' alt='properties'/>

            <?php if (strcmp($property->status, 'new') == 0) {
                ?>
                <div class='status sold'><?php $property->status ?></div>
            <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class='status new'><?php $property->status ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <h4><a href='property-detail.php'><?php $property->property_info ?></a></h4>
        <p class='price'><?php $property->prize ?></p>
        <div class='listing-detail'>
            <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Bed Room'>5</span> 
            <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Living Room'>2</span> 
            <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Parking'>2</span> 
            <span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Kitchen'>1</span>
        </div>
        <a class='btn btn-primary' href='property-detail.php'>View Details</a>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your file line of view is incorrect

```
< php foreach($this->Property_Model->getProperty() as $property): ?>
```

you forget `?` in your php tag

it should be

```
<?php foreach($this->Property_Model->getProperty() as $property): ?>
```

and you can call your model in controller not in view